# How to get value from a react function within a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to Reacj.js and having trouble getting value back from a function. I am not sure if I am doing it right. I need the function expression "func" to return "from func" and replace {this.func}. Not sure what I am missing.

```
var Hello = React.createClass({

    func: function(){
        return 'from func';
    },

    render: function() {
        return <div>
                    <div>Props: {this.props.name}</div>
                    <div>Function: {this.func}</div>
               </div>;
    }
});

React.render(<Hello name="from props" />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

I have the js fiddle in http://jsfiddle.net/rexonms/409d46av/

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You're almost there. Remember that everything inside { and } in JSX is just regular Javascript. And to get the return value from a function in Javascript, you have to call it. So something like this (notice the parens after `this.func`):

```
return (
  <div>
    <div>Props: {this.props.name}</div>
    <div>Function: {this.func()}</div>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: lol... thank you much for the answer @Anders Ekdahl. Now I feel like dumob. Should have read the documentation carefully :)

Comment: You can go as far as doing `prop={this.getcustomval.bind(this,args)()}`